# Can somebody help me with minesweeper?

Tags: c

I'm currently started learning C language.
And as my homework I'm trying to make a console version of minesweeper in C.
However, it somehow doesn't work and I don't know why.
The problem is, I'm not allowed to modify some of these functions and variables. They are

(init_board, display_board, show_interface)
these are what I'm not allowed to modify.

For 10*10 minesweeper,
my first thought was to make a 12*12 board and a function to calculate everything I need before first user input was made.

When user sweeps mined square, program terminates and it's just what I wanted so it works fine. However, when user sweeps unmined square, function reveal() seems not properly working.

Here's my flawed code.... Can somebody help me??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#define BOARD_SIZE              10
#define SQUARE_NUM              (BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE)
#define MINE_NUM                17
#define SHUFFLE_NUM             100000

int left_square;
int mines; // only for debugging

int end; // only 1 when player lose

int mine_board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
/* 0 : non-mined, 1 : mined */

int display_board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
/* -1 : no mines around, 0 : unknown, 1~8 : number of mines */

int board_revealed[BOARD_SIZE + 2][BOARD_SIZE + 2];
int calculate_board[BOARD_SIZE + 2][BOARD_SIZE + 2][2];
// 0 : non-mined, 1 : mined
// layer 0 : current mine state
// layer 1 : how many mines are nearby

void board_oracle();
void store_board(); // store mine_board to calculate_board
void init_board(); // initialize mine_board by randomly planting fixed number of mines
void show_interface(); // print display_board
void reveal(int x, int y);

int sweep(int x, int y);
/*
* return : 1 if player sweeps mined square, else 0
*/

int check_game();
/*
* check if the player swept all non-mined squares
* return : 1 if player swept all non-mined squares, else 0
*/

int main(void) //Todo
{
    init_board();
    show_interface();
    store_board();
    printf("%d unmined square remaining, %d mines here\n", left_square, mines); // debugging
    while (check_game() == 0)
    {
        int x, y;
        printf("input coordinate : ");
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        if (sweep(x, y) == 0)
        {
            reveal(x, y);
        }
        else
        {
            display_board[x - 1][y - 1] = -1;
            end = 1;
            show_interface();
            printf("player lost");
            return 0;
        }
        show_interface();
    }

}


void init_board()
{
    int i;
    int shuffle[BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE];
    int temp;
    int r1, r2;

    srand(time(NULL)); // set seed

                       // initialize shuffle array
    for (i = 0; i<SQUARE_NUM; i++)
        shuffle[i] = i;

    // shuffling
    for (i = 0; i<SHUFFLE_NUM; i++)
    {
        r1 = rand() % SQUARE_NUM;
        r2 = rand() % SQUARE_NUM;

        temp = shuffle[r1];
        shuffle[r1] = shuffle[r2];
        shuffle[r2] = temp;
    }

    // get mine coordinates from shuffled array
    for (i = 0; i<MINE_NUM; i++)
        mine_board[shuffle[i] / BOARD_SIZE][shuffle[i] % BOARD_SIZE] = 1;
}
//given

void show_interface()
{
    int i, j;

    system("cls"); // clear the screen

                     // rest of this function just prints out display_board
    printf("    ");
    for (i = 0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        printf(" %2d ", i + 1);
    for (i = 0; i<BOARD_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %2d ", i + 1);

        for (j = 0; j<BOARD_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (display_board[i][j] == -1)
            {
                if (mine_board[i][j] == 1)
                    printf("  * ");
                else
                    printf("  X ");
            }
            else if (display_board[i][j] == 0)
                printf("  - ");
            else
                printf("  %d ", display_board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n  |\n  v\n\n  Y\n\n");
}
//given

int sweep(int x, int y) // TODo
{
    if (calculate_board[x][y][0] == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
//done

int check_game()
{
    if (end == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (left_square == 0)
    {
        printf("You win");
        return 2; // indicates win
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

void store_board()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int x = i / 10; 
        int y = i % 10;
        calculate_board[x + 1][y + 1][0] = mine_board[x][y];
        if (calculate_board[x + 1][y + 1][0] == 0)
        {
            left_square++;
        }
        else
        {
            mines++;
        }
    }
}
// properly working.

void board_oracle()
{
    int i = 1, j = 1;
    for (; i < 11; i++)
    {
        for (; j < 11; j++)
        {
            calculate_board[i][j][1] = calculate_board[i - 1][j - 1][0] + calculate_board[i][j - 1][0] + calculate_board[i - 1][j][0] + calculate_board[i][j + 1][0] + calculate_board[i - 1][j + 1][0] + calculate_board[i + 1][j - 1][0] + calculate_board[i + 1][j][0] + calculate_board[i + 1][j + 1][0];
        }
    }
}

void reveal(int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x<= 11 && y <= 11)
    {
        if (board_revealed[x][y] == 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (calculate_board[x][y][1] == 0)
            {
                reveal(x - 1, y - 1);
                reveal(x - 1, y);
                reveal(x - 1, y + 1);
                reveal(x, y - 1);
                reveal(x, y + 1);
                reveal(x + 1, y - 1); 
                reveal(x + 1, y);
                reveal(x + 1, y + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                display_board[x - 1][y - 1] = calculate_board[x][y][1];
                board_revealed[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

As some comments say, to precisely state the problem
When I run the program and give input like 2 3, the program just crashes and says
"Segmentation error(core dumped)" 
When it is mined square, the error doesn't occurs (it prints "player lost" and done)
The error only occurs when I sweep non-mined square.

As some helps said, I added a line to make sure reveal() stops at edge...but it won't make it better...

Comment: What y6mean by "seems not properly working"?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. In particular, eliminate any user input unless that itself is the problem. Further, as mentioned above, your error description is only an interpretation but lacks the observations.

Comment: I stated the problem better. Can this help?

Comment: I googled about segmentation errors, but none of them seems to fit my case...

Comment: What does your debugger say? (What compiler/OS are you using?)

Comment: I tried visual studio and gcc

Comment: And visual studio just crashes... gcc says segmentation error(core dumped)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Visual Studio has a built-in debugger. With gcc you could use gdb.

Comment: Seems reveal can reach edge of the border... and go further.

Comment: I changed the code so it wouldn't reach the edge, but the problem still isn't solved. I get the same error....
I added if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x<= 11 && y <= 11) to reveal()...

Comment: Bad algorithm. It goes over and over same coordinates infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

```
test.c: In function 'reveal':
test.c:221:41: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
         display_board[x - 1][y - 1] == calculate_board[x][y][1];
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This should be a `=`. But more importantly you should enable compiler warnings, for example on gcc with `-Wall`.

Problem 2:

When I choose `2 2` then the function `reveal`gets called with coordinates: 
`2 2   1 1    0  0    -1 -1   -1 0   -2 -1    -3 -2    -4 -3`. So it has to crash eventually, no matter if you made the grid a little larger. At the point where you call `reveal` 8 times you should first check whether the coordinate is valid ie >=0 and < n. Then maybe you also dont need to make the grid larger at all.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it again!

Comment: Ah... wouldn't it be sufficient if I add if (x >= 1 && y >= 1 && x<= 11 && y <= 11) to the reveal?

Comment: I did that but nothing happened..

Comment: You edited the sourcecode in your question which makes it harder for people to follow the discussion. Next time you could append to your question "EDIT" followed by the new source. The problem now is that there is a loop (again i started by selecting cell 2, 2 ): (1, 1) (0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (1, 0) (1, 2) (0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) (1, 1) loop

Comment: Won't the board_revealed[x][y] prevent the flaw?

Comment: I thought that it would prevent infinite loop....

Comment: board_revealed[x][y] does not prevent the loop because it is only set in the else-branch but the else-branch is never entered. Just play through the example (2, 2) goes to (1, 1) goes to ... (see above). To improve it you could write the `board_revealed[x][y] = 1;` before the line `if (calculate_board[x][y][1] == 0)`